# Refactor existing C structure to accommodate more elements

Tags: c, data-structures, refactoring

I have a C language sniffer program.
There is a list to record how many packages (packets) caught per source ip and destination ip pair.
Like I got such packages:

```
[192.168.1.1] -> [192.168.1.2] Total package amount:[100]
[192.168.1.3] -> [192.168.1.4] Total package amount:[100]
[192.168.1.4] -> [192.168.1.3] Total package amount:[100]
```

My structure is:

```
 struct node {
  u_char s_ip[16];        //source IP
  u_char d_ip[16];        //destination IP
  u_int32_t package_amount;   //Would be sum
  struct node *next;
};
struct node *head;      
struct node *search;      //(1)position (2)for new malloc
struct node *tail;
```

But as you know, TCP and UDP have ports, so I want to add port fields to my structure, then it looks like:

```
struct tu_node {
  u_char s_ip[16];        //source IP
  u_char d_ip[16];        //destination IP
  u_int32_t s_port;      //source port
  u_int32_t d_port;      //destination port
  u_int32_t package_amount;   
  struct node *next;
};
struct tu_node *tu_head;         // tu means tcp and udp
struct tu_node *tu_search;    
struct tu_node *tu_tail;
```

Although My sniffer is limited in that it can only parse TCP and UDP, I want to print out unknown protocols package amount per s_ip and d_ip pairs. As you see, now the port fields (s_port and d_port) are NOT applicable to unknown protocols. The simple way to me is to define a new struct, like:

```
struct unknown_node {
  u_char s_ip[16];        //source IP
  u_char d_ip[16];        //destination IP
  u_int32_t package_amount;   
  struct node *next;
};
struct unknown_node *unknown_head;      
struct unknown_node *unknown_search;      
struct unknown_node *unknown_tail;
```

Now I've got a problem.
As I have two different structures, so I need two different functions to handle the list operations (head, search and tail) basically.

So could anyone help me to think about how to redesign/refactor above structures or give me a point to refactor my list functions, to be a good design?

---

So far, I got two probable but unclear methods:

1. One is use something like `#if` in `struct node` (the first code snippet) to accommodate d_port and s_port. But I don't think it is feasible because sniffer only know TCP and UDP at runtime, but `#if` directives need be fixed at compile time.
2. The second one is think about how to implement "overload" function to compatible "struct tu_node" and "struct unknown_node" both. But seems C language can't.

Comment: why do you need to remove the ports ? wouldn't be easier to just not print them ?

Comment: Emm, I want to save space. And I don't like redundant fields in my structure. I like to be concise.

Comment: You want to save space, but your structures are configured to handle IPv6 when most systems still use IPv4.  Saving 4 bytes for 2 port numbers is false economy compared with the cost of handling the two structure types.  On most 64-bit machines, you'll have 4 bytes of padding where the two 2-byte port numbers would be stored anyway, so you won't waste any space.

Comment: if you want to save some space you should start by storing the IPs in binary (4 bytes assuming IPv4) not in ASCII (16 bytes) and using `short` for the ports, there I saved you lots of space :)

Comment: Obviously, you guys are good at arithmetic LOL. Thank you all for your proffessional comments. Regardless of the space, could you please think in way that I want? I wonder whether there is an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your answer lies in your second question, in that since C does not support overloading, so you have one of two choices: **use the subset of C that C++ supports** as that subset allows overloading.

Or, **write a function that can handle both types of structs.** Since this isn't possible in ANSI C, it would be a better idea to simply support both protocols in your struct definition and determine which one is being used.

**A third and final option is to use a library.** If this is not for an assignment, I'd highly recommend using a library designed for such purposes in addition to studying similar implementations.

One that comes to mind is the **tcpdump and libcap** libraries:

http://www.tcpdump.org/

Why a third party suggestion? I don't mean to sound pedantic but, unless it's an academic exercise or mainly for self-learning, it bodes well to use libraries where possible - rather than roll out your own (unless you have reason to do so). Time is your most important asset. It behooves you to be efficient about how you use it.

Here are a couple of examples that you can examine to see if tcpdump and libcap are worth exploring: http://eecs.wsu.edu/~sshaikot/docs/lbpcap/libpcap-tutorial.pdf
http://simplestcodings.blogspot.com/2010/10/create-your-own-packet-sniffer-in-c.html?q=sniffer

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot jrd! Yup, this sniffer is one of my excercises. So I won't to use a third lib. But your answers in the beginning really do me a favor. I will explor them more. Thank you again.